# split string in ios string from json data?

Tags: ios, iphone, json, string

I have one string. Now I wanted to split this string. For static separation I know the code but I don’t code for dynamic value.

my string is

```
NSString *str = @"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/181054825200000/feed?fields=created_time,message,picture,full_picture,comments.limit%280%29.summary%28true%29,likes.limit%280%29.summary%28true%29&limit=5&format=json&access_token=CAALjFrE5mNYBAOg1EDiUrsE2kr1kIRrLIv7g4OweSMvHso2exB5Dttshn7dgOlW24ZCXSnDZAWiV6xMUKXedTXUhiHpdmZBPCGzD1orFlrLRP2gaBZCbZBZBnjUHewF9hZBmJKxtiwVzpw9gnnQXk5Hfx0ZBM2ksAUzkSWR5feaNMbf3UUmUpJlxeh0gKdDrzWBvIJRPy0xGqL0ZAMFsRhyCZCTX42l1sZAceZB0VCeDZB95mrAZDZD&until=1456345291&__paging_token=enc_AdCKD3tSYMoZB3MCKaJkYnbVmBgUyY2tBceGDD2G1hqxRDiQKZCsSbmvWZASLvlCMf0BVzq2uZAScSWp7ZAavZB2d72BIHJISefk09noRuv9gA5b5hFwZDZD";
```

but i don’t how to show any value dynamically .(for e.g. until (in string))

please help me for this issue.

Thank You.

Comment: I didn't get this **I know the code but I don’t code**, you can always have constant for static string URL, or Message etc.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are asking. What result are you looking for? How do you want to split your string?

Comment: can you add some more code , your question is not clear

Comment: totally unclear what is meant by **show any value dynamically**. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Ok, my understanding is that OP knows how to split the string at a particular index, but doesn't not know how to split it at a dynamically determined place, eg first occurrence of a pattern. OP can you confirm?

Comment: You are right ! @ewanc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are parsing a URL you should really use NSURLComponents. It makes breaking a URL into the different parts much easier, and the code is tested and verified by Apple.

Answer (score 1):

For separate string by a separator you can use this.

```
NSString *url = @"<url>";
NSArray *array = [url componentsSeparatedByString:@"<seperator string>"];
NSLog(@"%@", array);
```

But for URL parsing ,As per Duncan's answer, yes it is good to parse a URL using `NSURLComponents`. By using this class you can get any desired part of an URL.